# Javascript into html isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am very, very new to html, but I am trying to try out a widget made by NCBO BioPortal. The widget is a javascript file that allows the admin to restrict a form field to certain terms pulled from an external vocabulary. Thanks for any insight you can give as to why it isn't working!

Here's the link for the widget: http://bioportal.bioontology.org/javascripts/widgets/form_complete.js

Here's what it's supposed to do:

-Look-ahead so that you don't need to type the whole term
-Controlled vocabulary provides consistency of the way different users use the term

Here's my HTML, written by following the guidelines on this page:
https://www.bioontology.org/wiki/index.php/NCBO_Widgets#Term-selection_field_on_a_form

```
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://bioportal.bioontology.org/javascripts/widgets/form_complete.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> NCBO Widget tester </title>

</head>

<body>
<body style="background-color:3a64a8">
<h1> NCBO Widget Tester </h1>
<p>Term Selection in a field</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Term tagger:<br>
  <input type="text" name="term" class="bp_form_complete-all-name" size="100"/><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but looks like your script is running before page is loaded.
You need to put your script bellow your html code in body or add `defer` to  your `<script>` tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://bioportal.bioontology.org/javascripts/widgets/form_complete.js " defer></script>
```

Comment: Putting a script tag at the end of the body doesn't guarantee that it won't load after the DOM renders.  That's why jQuery coders commonly wrap their code in `$(function() { });`

Comment: Thanks)
Note that I'm also new in JS and just try to help

Comment: @VtoCorleone It does guarantee that it will load after the DOM is ready, so you don't need `$(function() {});` if the script is at the end of the `</body>` tag